# How do I find images based on their numbers in the Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, home-folder, search-folder

I have 1,015 images in a folder and this image is classified into seven types and these types are categories of medical diagnoses of skin cancer, and the same images are classified in the Excel file by number (the number of each picture corresponds to the type of diagnosis of this image).
Clearly, each image has a specific number corresponding to the diagnostic type, my question is how to sort these images in the folder in groups so that each group of images have the same diagnosis.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no `Diagnosis` column in your data. And it is unclear what result does you want to achieve.

Comment: diagnosis column is has label " dx" , I want to search  for multiple of image files at once from the folder (ISIC2018_task 3_training_input) , like (ISIC_27320, ISIC_24306, ISIC_25370, and so on )

Comment: Well... you want to search... you searches... then? what result does you want to achieve? to send the found filenames list to a printer? to build anagramma from them? to summ the numbers in filenames? to calculate average image size? WHAT IS THE RESULT WHICH YOU NEED?

Comment: You asked me what result I wanted to achieve ,well, I want to search for multiple files in this folder at once , like (SIC_27320, ISIC_24306, ISIC_25370 ,SIC_27320, ISIC_29306, ISIC_33472, .......) by windows search

Comment: *I want to search for multiple files in this folder at once* This is process. Whereas I have asked about visible final result. For example, you may want to mark all found filenames in your worksheet with some color. Or open Explorer window with all these files selected. Or put filenames list on newly inserted worksheet. Or move these files into subfolder. Or something else. I don't know how to explain more clear...

Answer (score 1):

You can try an approch like the following in powershell 
It can certainly be optimized,  but I wanted it simple to understand with 2 steps :
- The first one :  creation of the target tree according to your input file (.csv)
- The second one : moving image files in the corresponding subdirectories)

```
#The process : 
$BasedImages = "\\path\to\ImagesDirectory"
$csvfile = "\\path\to\Inputcsvfile.csv"

#Gather all subfolders in the Images Directory (only first level) and put the name of these folder in a var. The only property useful for later use is the Directory name. Useless to gather all properties 
$ExistingSubDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $BasedImages -Directory | Select-Object -Property name

# Gather unique diagnosis in the input file and put in a var. The only useful property in the dx property for a later use. Useless to collect more info. 
$UniqueDiagnosis = Import-Csv -Path $csvfile | Select-Object -property dx -Unique

# gather all images files FullName in the Images Directory and put in a var. it seems that only  Name,DirectoryName, FullName properties will be usefull for later use
$AllImagesFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $BasedImages -File | Select-Object -Property Name, DirectoryName FullName

# now First Step : build a Tree with  subfolders named by the unique Diagnosis name. 
foreach ($Diagnosis in $UniqueDiagnosis)
    { 
    # search if a diagnosis dir name (dx field in the input .csv file) exist in the ImageDirectory and put the result in a var
    if ($ExistingSubDir -contains $Diagnosis) 
        { 
        Write-Host "$ExistingSubDir is still existing, no action at this step" -ForegroundColor Green 
        }
    else
        {
        New-Item -Path $BasedImages -Name $Diagnosis -ItemType Directory
        Write-Host "a sub-directory named $Diagnosis has been created in the folder $BasedImages" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }

# At this step, you'll have some sub directories named with the name of all diagnosis (fied dx in the input file)
# Now Step 2 Time to move the files in the root folder
foreach ($image in $AllImagesFiles)
    { 
    $TargetSubDir = Get-Item -Path $($image.fullName)
    Move-Item -Path $($Image.FullName) -Destination ( Join-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $($Image.DirectoryName) -Parent) -ChildPath $TargetSubDir)
    Write-Host "the image named $($image.name) has been moved to the sud directory $TargetSubDir" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
```

Careful, i haven't completly tested the code, use with caution.

Oliv

Comment: How can i execute this code ?

Comment: I have run the code by windows powershell , But I didn't get any result.

Comment: I have run the code above , but I didn't understand. Can I change the path of the images folder and the Excel file to what is on my computer?, also i get an error with " full name" in code .